# IOS demo app, as screensaver

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have to develop an app, that runs when noone touches an iPhone. I have the app to run, but I need a solution, to play the app. Main key: I can't jailbreak the phone.

If there would be anyone, who can help me, i would be greatful.

Comment: As Andrew Miner pointed out, you can't make iOS screensavers. You could make a "screensaver" within your own app and just lock the iPhone to always be inside of that app.

Comment: I see. What I need, is a retail-mode-alike behavior. It doesn't metter, if it is  a screensaver, or anything. How could I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on the phone which can notify you if there have been no touches in any app for a certain length of time.  Moreover, iOS devices don't require screensavers as they are not subject to [screen burn-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set up an iOS device for retail demo use is to use [guided access](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5509). This mode can lock your device to a specific app. So just make an app that serves as an appropriate retail demo and lock the device to it.